# SAP Logon Error - Detail NiRClientHandle: route expected

Tags: ubuntu, sap-gui, sap-basis

**The Error:**

```
Connection closed
Error: internal error
Location: SAProuter 40.4 on 'uccsaprouter'
Tue Jan 30 20:35:02 2018
Release 720
Component NI (network interface), version 40
rc = -93, module nirout.cpp, line 2754
Detail NiRClientHandle: route expected
```

---

**The Story:**

I have installed the *Java* Version of **SAPGUI 7.4** on *Ubuntu*. However, when I changed to `cd ~/.SAPGUI` I did not find any *configuration* file which suppose to be set up by the administrator (who I do not have as it is for the class!). Our lecturer provided us with these information:

```
[Router]
hcctum=/H/saprouter.hcc.in.tum.de/S/3299/H/
hccmdA=/H/141.44.38.2/S/3299/H/
hccmdM=/H/141.44.39.3/S/3299/H/
hcctumremote=/H/saprouter.hcc.in.tum.de/S/3297/H/
hcctumfailover=/H/hcchasap.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/S/3299/H/

[Default]
name=hcctum
```

which I put in a configuration file and link it in:

```
Preferences -> Configuration -> Logon -> Configuration File
```

When I checked the **setting** file that resides in `~/.SAPGUI`:

```
############################################################
#
# file    : /home/user/.SAPGUI/settings
# created : 18.01.2018 20:17:10 GMT
# encoding: UTF-8
#
############################################################
@logonFrame_2_Y = "245"
@GLF_combidivider = "150"
@logonFrame_2_X = "384"
@LSSelection = "18f696cf-b8c2-4b69-b5c5-8eeb2dfe24d0:432f7f69-e058-4088-99c9-517a37ab09a4"
@GLF_recent = "432f7f69-e058-4088-99c9-517a37ab09a4"
@INCLUDE = "/home/user/Downloads/saprouter.ini"
@ftpProxyHost = ""
@httpProxyHost = ""
@httpProxyPort = "0"
@proxyMode = "0"
@httpsProxyPort = "0"
@ftpProxyPort = "0"
@httpProxyIgnore = ""
@httpsProxyHost = ""
```

And the **SAPGUILandscape.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Landscape updated="2018-01-30T19:25:55Z" version="1" origin="file:/home/user/.SAPGUI/SAPGUILandscape.xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" generator="SAP GUI for Java 7.40 rev 4" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SAPUILandscape.xsd">
  <Services>
    <Service name="test" expert="1" msid="" uuid="82aa1de3-76db-4e7d-b047-69a9e5b46ed8" type="SAPGUI" server="saprouter.hcc.in.tum.de:3297" mode="1"/>
  </Services>
  <Workspaces default="18f696cf-b8c2-4b69-b5c5-8eeb2dfe24d0">
    <Workspace expanded="1" name="JavaGUI Services" uuid="18f696cf-b8c2-4b69-b5c5-8eeb2dfe24d0" description="JavaGUI Services configuration">
      <Item uuid="432f7f69-e058-4088-99c9-517a37ab09a4" serviceid="82aa1de3-76db-4e7d-b047-69a9e5b46ed8"/>
    </Workspace>
  </Workspaces>
  <Messageservers>
    <Messageserver port="3297" name="MS" uuid="15b91bd3-5e4e-4887-aeea-939df9379517" host="saprouter.hcc.in.tum.de"/>
  </Messageservers>
  <Routers>
    <Router router="/" name="Router" uuid="5e119945-5975-4567-ab35-b1142568383f"/>
```

After one week of trials, any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your file is invalid. There are ways to validate your **SAPGUILandscape.xml** (see note [2112449](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2112449)), or trying to read hundred-page manuals ([1](https://www.sap.com/documents/2014/12/34fbd951-5a7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html), [2](https://www.sap.com/documents/2014/10/bed91652-5a7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html)), but better not to dig into all this mess and try to stick these simple steps.

SAPgui Java has following connection string format:

```
 conn=/H/<SAP Router>/S/3299/H/<SAP server>/S/32<Instance_no>
```

Multiple routers (if exist) are separated by `/H/` directive.

So I propose you **to delete all config files** (`~/.SAPGUI` folder), SAPgui will recreate them anyway. After deletion open SAPgui and enter connection string [manually](http://forum.fandezhi.com/index.php?u=/serve/attachment&path=570945d0a845a.png) like this:

```
conn=/H/saprouter.hcc.in.tum.de/S/3299/H/141.44.38.2/S/3299/H/141.44.39.3/S/3299/H/saprouter.hcc.in.tum.de/S/3297/H/hcchasap.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/S/3299/H/hcctum/S/3201
```

If errors are thrown try to remove some of the routers, ping each of them, detect invalid ones and also ping server (hcctum).

Dunno what is `[Default]` in your lecturer's notes, but I suppose it denotes server. It is non-standard section (see note [94435](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/99435)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and plus one from me. I did exactly as you told but got new error: `Connection failed Error: accesscluster: route permission denied (131.159.8.236 to 141.44.39.3, 3299) Location: SAProuter 40.4 on 'accesscluster'`

Comment: I tried to `ping` each router, some of them reachable, others are not. However, I kept only the pingable ones and still `permission denied` issue! Any suggestion?

Comment: It's [purely admin error](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e245703406684d8a81812f4c6334eb2f/7.40.17/en-US/6fcfb4c26420423e8e348075463f27eb.html) that cannot be fixed on your side. Ask your professor for new config and/or ask him to change SAProuter settings to allow your IP.